# Вирус на WordPress, редиректит на рекламу

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, безопасность

Добрый день. Обратился хороший знакомый, попросил убрать вирус с его сайта, не знаю как он туда попал. Пароли на FTP, Админке вордпресса сменил. Сейчас пытаюсь найти откуда растут ноги, ставил различные антивирусы на WordPress, убрал весь подозрительный код о котором писали эти антивирусы, ничего не помогло. Проверил htaccess, там тоже всё чисто.

Вордпрес последней версии. Гуглил, все советы выполнил, ничего не помогло.

Сайт [xn--80acubhvsggp.xn--p1ai](http://xn--80acubhvsggp.xn--p1ai) (РФ домен)

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по наличию вредоносного кода в файле `/wp-content/themes/reason/javascripts/mobile-adjust.js` вы либо удалили не всё, либо код откуда-то снова добавляется.

Пишите хостинг-провайдеру, просите проверить наличие дыр с его стороны.
Проверьте записи в БД.
Ну и удалите все вставки вида `var _0xaae8=["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","...` из своих js-файлов (проверяйте все js-файлы темы, указанный код добавлен в конце как минимум двух из них).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, почти все JS были заражены.

Comment: Почитайте на досуге https://www.polaris64.net/blog/cyber-security/2017/wordpress-hacks-jquery-js-script-injection это как раз полностью про ваш случай

Answer (score 0):

> Что делать?

Лучше всего обратиться к специалистам.

[Продублирую](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-include_once/#post-243874):

Ну а так — нужно заменить всё ядро ВП (лучше не обновление из консоли, а через удаление на хостинге каталогов `wp-admin`, `wp-includes` и файлов ВП в корне), удалить лишние файлы (везде! Включая каталоги ядра, если обновлялось из консоли и не имеющие к нему отношения), избавиться от уязвимостей (это, как правило, **взятые непонятно откуда и старые темы и плагины**) и опасных/лишних строк в нужных файлах (хтацесс, конфиг и др). Это скорее всего поможет, но тоже не факт, что будет почищено всё полностью.

Comment: А если я снесу все файлы, предварительно сохранив wp-content и wp-config, поставлю новый вордпресс и верну wp-content и wp-config, не сломаю ли сайт? И может ли помочь?

Comment: Если в ядро не вносилось изменений (чего делать категорически нельзя!), то ничего не должно поломаться. Но если притянешь всё те же дырявые темы/плагины и/или др файлы в wp-content и в корне. то всё останется как было. И, если по уму, то кроме корня сайта нужно проверять и др каталоги на хостинге. И базу.

Comment: Не могло, снес все кроме этих двух файлов, поставил чистые файлы..) Значит в wp-content вирусня сидит.)

Comment: Может и в базе. Может и выше корня. Но скрее всего да - тема (она же мутная какая-то, самопал не из репо) или/и плагины

Comment: Проверьте папку uploads на файлы *.php. Если есть, то поудаляйте. Также временно, пока точно не будете уверены, что вирусы вычищены, поставьте систему слежения за изменением файлов. Есть вариант поставить Git или что-то такое www.novostrim.com. Пройдитесь по файлам утилитой ai-bolit